# how to call separate logic for diff file name in spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, readfile

I have 3 log files in my folders.
Like

```
foldera = emplog,deptlog,companylog
folderb = emplog,deptlog,companylog
folderc = emplog,deptlog,companylog
```

I have 3 diff scala program file to extract the data from each of them.

```
employee.scala
department.scala
companylog.scala
```

Each of them code like below.

I want to combine all these files and execute them paralleled manner.

```
   package com.sample
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.rddToPairRDDFunctions
import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext
import org.apache.log4j.{Level, Logger}

object logparser {
  def main(args: Array[String]) = {

      Logger.getLogger("org").setLevel(Level.OFF)     
      Logger.getLogger("akka").setLevel(Level.OFF)
    //Start the Spark context
    val conf = new SparkConf()
      .setAppName("Parser")
      .setMaster("local")

      val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
      val sqlContext= new SQLContext(sc)

      val test = sc.wholeTextFiles("C:\\mkdir\\*\\*")
      .map{l =>
             if(l._1.endsWith("emplog.txt")){ 
             empparser(l._2,sc,sqlContext)
               }

             l
        }
      .foreach{println}
  }

  def empparser(record:String,sc:SparkContext,sqlContext:SQLContext) = {
     val emppattern="""[(](\d+)[)]\s([\w\s._]{30})\s+""".r

      import sqlContext.implicits._
     val indrecs = emppattern.findAllIn(record)
    .map{ line => 
      val emppattern(eid,ename) = line

     (eid,ename)
    }
     .toSeq
   .toDF("eid","ename")

   .show() 


  }
}
```

I have tried my code in attaching each method within same object.

Now 2 questions arise
Q1. When I compile I get

```
Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: org.apache.spark.SparkContext
Serialization stack:
    - object not serializable (class: org.apache.spark.SparkContext, value: org.apache.spark.SparkContext@6b0615ae)
    - field (class: com.sample.logparser$$anonfun$1, name: sc$1, type: class org.apache.spark.SparkContext)
    - object (class com.sample.logparser$$anonfun$1, <function1>)
```

As far as I know(newbie only) Spark context can't be serialized. If I dont pass sc as parameter, I get Nullpointer Exception. How do I solve this?

Q2 :I will insert to hive table code within empparser method after converting to DF. Once that done , I dont want to do anything within my main. But my map code wont execute unless I have action after that. thats why I have foreacch println after that. Is there way to overcome this issue?

Comment: If you've just got three, read each into an RDD in turn, map that RDD to have a key of the filename, then `union`them into one.

Comment: You need to consider the Scala logic as classes / functions, not "scala files".     Then you will need some discriminator to map a data file to some logic. Maybe filename, maybe file contents? I wouldn't know as the question is not specific enough. Try adding the processing logic and a data sample to the question.  Also, I suggest you do more research before posting. There're many resources that cover this kind of problem

Comment: updated the question with logic.

Comment: You cannot "nest" Spark operations as the Spark Context is undefined on th executors. Return a value from the `map` function and do your DataFrame ops on the driver code.

Comment: Okay. I rewrote the code as you suggested. From empparser method, removed .toSeq  .toDF("eid","ename")   .show() , added to return type to it. And in main method addded these codes right after .map{} call. Its working as expected. One doubt . Does it mean, all my code will run in single node mode or still these code will be executed parellal way?

Comment: How are you partitioning the data? How many nodes do you have in your cluster?

Comment: What I have mentioned is my complete code. (1)I ll be reading files from my hdfs location not from c:\ in that wholeTextFiles ). I will be reading around 6000 small files(max 50mb) thru that single line. I assume it willl create 6000(k,v) pairs or(filename,content) which will automatically splitted & scaled across nodes. I have 3 nodes in my cluster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To attempt to answer the question, I'm going to assume that the result of processing a employee or a department results in the same *kind* of record. I would expect this to be different for each kind of data so I'm keeping the processing of different kinds of records separately to allow for this "adjustment with reality".

First, we define a record `case class` and parsers for the different kind or record types. (Here I'm copying the same impl for the sake of simplicity)

```
case class Record(id:String, name: String)

val empParser: String =>  Option[Record] = { record => 
  val pattern="""^[(](\d+)[)]\s([\w\s._]{30})\s+$""".r
  record match {
    case pattern(eid,ename) => Some(Record(eid, ename))
    case _ => None
  }
}

val deptParser: String =>  Option[Record] = { record => 
  val pattern="""^[(](\d+)[)]\s([\w\s._]{30})\s+$""".r
  record match {
    case pattern(eid,ename) => Some(Record(eid, ename))
    case _ => None
  }
}

val companyParser: String =>  Option[Record] = { record => 
  val pattern="""^[(](\d+)[)]\s([\w\s._]{30})\s+$""".r
  record match {
    case pattern(eid,ename) => Some(Record(eid, ename))
    case _ => None
  }
}
```

We load the data using `wholeFiles`:

```
val dataPath = "/.../data/wholefiles/*/*"
val logFiles =  sc.wholeTextFiles(dataPath)
```

And then, we process the different kind of records by filtering the files to obtain the kind of files that we require and apply the parser we defined above. Note how we are practically repeating the same process. This could be abstracted out.

```
val empLogs = logFiles.filter{case (filename, content) => filename.endsWith("emplog.txt")}.flatMap{case (_,content) => content.split("\n").flatMap(line=> empParser(line))}
val deptLogs = logFiles.filter{case (filename, content) => filename.endsWith("deptlog.txt")}.flatMap{case (_,content) => content.split("\n").flatMap(line=> deptParser(line))}
val compLogs = logFiles.filter{case (filename, content) => filename.endsWith("companylog.txt")}.flatMap{case (_,content) => content.split("\n").flatMap(line=> companyParser(line))}
```

We now convert to a DataFrame

```
val empDF  = empLogs.toDF
```

And we could do the same for the other record types as well.

There's plenty of room to reduce code duplication in this process depending on whether we can find commonalities in the processes of the different data types.

Comment: Thanks maasg for detailed explanation